# Selecting a property with a variable name

Tags: excel, vba, syntax-error

```
Dim i As Integer
i = 1
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Label & i.Caption = "Checked"
```

I get a syntax error for the above code, could someone please help me specify a property name as a variable so that I could do things like running this through a for loop to apply this to multiple labels.

Thanks.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a Form control, then:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Label " & i).TextFrame.Characters.Text  = "Checked"
```

If it's an ActiveX contol:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).OLEObjects("Label" & i).Object.Caption = "Checked"
```